# Loop over interface{} containing a map[int]*somepointer

Tags: go

I have to deal with a lot of maps with int keys which contain pointers to different datatypes.

I need a function (and not 10 functions for each map type) to range over those maps and get the maximum and minimum key values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the reflect package to operate on maps with integer keys and arbitrary value types:

```
func getMaxKey(inout interface{}) int {
    keys := reflect.ValueOf(inout).MapKeys()
    if len(keys) == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    max := keys[0].Int()
    for _, key := range keys[1:] {
        n := key.Int()
        if n > max {
            max = n
        }
    }
    return int(max)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nJp_9JC36yE).

Comment: I specifically avoided reflect as it has a reputation of having an impact on performance. But now that I think about it... it may well be that Marshal and Unmarshal also use reflect in this case. Thanks for the input.

Comment: The encoding/json package uses the reflect package.  Direct use of the reflect package is more efficient than using the reflect package through the encoding/json package.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up with. It might also work for other map types:

https://play.golang.org/p/-T8s-bPCNm4

- It allows to have passed in any map of type map[int]*somepointer
- No type assertion needed (in this case)

-

```
func getMaxKey(inout interface{}) int {
    auxMap:= make(map[int]string)
    body, _ := json.Marshal(inout)
        json.Unmarshal(body, &auxMap)
    maxKey := 0
        for key,_ := range auxMap {
        if key > maxKey {
            maxKey = key
        }
    }
    return maxKey
}


func getMinKey(inout interface{}) int {
    auxMap:= make(map[int]string)
    body, _ := json.Marshal(inout)
        json.Unmarshal(body, &auxMap)
    minKey := 0
        for key,_ := range auxMap {
        if key < minKey || minKey == 0 {
            minKey = key
        }
    }
    return minKey
}
```